# Odd error message behavior when flagging as a duplicate

Tags: bug, status-norepro, flags, error-message

I tried flagging an answer as a duplicate of another answer and got this error:

[image: When flagging a duplicate, please specify the duplicate question (id or link)]

I experimented with a few different flag messages:

- "Duplicate of {short question link}" -- error message
- "Duplicate of {short answer link}" -- error message
- "Duplicate of {long question link}" -- works
- "Duplicate of {long answer link}" -- works
- "Duplicate of {short question link} (foobar)" -- works
- "Duplicate." -- works

This error seems like it was designed specifically to catch the last case, but it lets it through, and it rejects messages with short-form links (`http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118863/145982` instead of `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118863/odd-behavior-of-error-message-when-flagging-as-a-duplicate`)... unless they contain more text after the link

<sub>(The message also says "duplicate question", even when flagging an answer)</sub>

Comment: What text did you include after the short link to make it work?

Comment: @Gabe "(foobar)" and "(test)" both worked for me; I assume anything does

Comment: that is very strange...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this issue in the current build of our network sites.